# list index out of range Python despite research of the same

Tags: python

I have looked at all of the other posts that have the same question as this. I might be wrong but the only solution I saw that might be of help is list comprehensions but I am not sure if list comprehensions are even possible in this case. I have made sure that my variable i is an actually index and not a value. I may be wrong but I can't see why this code is not working out for me. I am using Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10 64 bit Dell laptop. Here is the code and thanks for the help in advance.

```
def swap(a, b):
    return b, a

def bubble_sort(array):
    swaps = 0
    passes = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
            array[i], array[i + 1] = swap(array[i], array[i + 1])
            swaps += 1
        passes += 1
    print(passes, swaps)
    return array

array = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6]
print("Array before sort is " + str(array))
array = bubble_sort(array)
print("Array after sort is " + str(array))
```

My main goals are to figure out the cause of this error and I would prefer a solution that I can successfully run without any errors. Please try not to give solutions that will only result in more errors. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: since this is homework, providing a complete solution would be doing you a disservice.

Comment: If you want to find out the cause of the error, read your own code. If `i in range(len(array))`, and you're using `array[i] > array[i + 1]`, what happens when `i = len(array)`? Try to think about what the code is doing instead of just typing. Every one of those other questions is answered by *the problem is you're exceeding the valid iindexes of the /array/list/whatever*.

Answer (score 0):

Error is resulting from this statement most likely  `if array[i] > array[i + 1]`, because when `i` reaches `len(array)` i.e. 8 in this case , then your logic is trying to access `array[7] > array [7 +1 ]` , but array[8] doesnt exists, so it throws index out of range error.

Comment: I tried adding "if (i + 1) > len(array): break" but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I see the possible reason why the line I added didn't work. Because len(array) is 8. Maybe if I add the line "If (i + 1) > (len(array) - 1)". I don't know.

Comment: I meant "if (i + 1) > (len(array) - 1): break"

Comment: Well looks like "if (i + 1) > (len(array) - 1): break" at least got rid of the error but the output is still not what I expected. Will keep working at it.

Comment: I am happy to report that I changed my code to use a nested for loop instead of just one for loop; at the beginning of each loop I put a line of code that goes "if (i + 1) > (len(array) - 1): break" and everything works great as expected with no errors. Much thanks to everybody for the help. Still learning how to use this site so I need to find out how to up vote answers. I don't think I have good enough reputation to do that yet but thanks to everybody.